# How to add additional user information while the user is logged in?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have created a login in page and now want to redirect the user to a page to add additional user information. How do I ensure that the user is "logged in" and that the information is added to that user's profiles? I know I need to use something like user=User.objects.get(email=email) to identify the user but I don't want to have the user enter their email on every single page to identify themselves.  Is there something I can pass to keep the user Logged-in?

Here is the view:

```
def add_user_profile(request):
    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form = AddUserProfileForm(request.POST)
        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required
            # ...
            # redirect to a new URL:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/summary/')

    # if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
    else:
        form = AddUserProfileForm()


    return render(request, 'registration/add_user_profile.html', {'form': form})
```

Here is the form:

```
class AddUserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):

    this_year = datetime.date.today().year
    Years = range(this_year-70, this_year+1)

    required_css_class = 'required'
    first_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'First Name'}), label="")
    middle_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Middle Name'}), label="")
    last_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Last Name'}), label="")
    date_of_birth = forms.DateField(widget=forms.extras.widgets.SelectDateWidget(years=Years))
    Primary_address = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Primary address'}), label="")
    Primary_address_zipcode = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Zip Code'}), label="")

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'middle_name', 'last_name', 'date_of_birth', 'Primary_address', 'Primary_address_zipcode')
```

Here is the url.py

```
url(r'^add_user_profile/$',
                       views.add_user_profile,
                       name='add_user_profile'),
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create a view which will deal with `request.user`. If your `update_profile` functionality is rather simple you may take a look at [UpdateView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#updateview). You just need to overwrite `get_object()` to look like this:

```
def get_object(self, queryset=None):
    return self.request.user
```

After this you just need to set up you `UpdateView` and create a proper template. You can read about this in the docs.